# Loop in folder and delete .xlsm file

Tags: excel, vba

Dears,

I create a code to loop through a folder and delete files which are 10 years old but the loop don't work properly since FolderPath (a variable) remain the same and loop follow an infinite loop.any help?

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

Dim FolderPath As String

FolderPath = Dir("C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\*.xlsm")

 Do While FolderPath <> ""
    If DateValue( _
                    Mid(FolderPath, InStr(FolderPath, ".") + 1, 2) & "/" & _
                    Mid(FolderPath, InStr(FolderPath, ".") + 3, 2) & "/" & _
                    Mid(FolderPath, InStr(FolderPath, ".") + 5, 4)) _
        < DateValue(Date - 10) Then

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            SetAttr "C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\" & FolderPath, vbNormal
            Kill "C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\" & FolderPath
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        FolderPath = Dir

    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move `FolderPath = Dir`,
Currently it is inside the IF statement, meaning it will only look for the next file if the current one is older then 10 days.

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

Dim FolderPath As String

FolderPath = Dir("C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\*.xlsm")

 Do While FolderPath <> ""
    If DateValue( _
                    Mid(FolderPath, InStr(FolderPath, ".") + 1, 2) & "/" & _
                    Mid(FolderPath, InStr(FolderPath, ".") + 3, 2) & "/" & _
                    Mid(FolderPath, InStr(FolderPath, ".") + 5, 4)) _
        < DateValue(Date - 10) Then

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            SetAttr "C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\" & FolderPath, vbNormal
            Kill "C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\" & FolderPath
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
  FolderPath = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: And could probably put "C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\" into a separate variable for ease of maintenance. +1

Comment: @QHarr thanks for your response but i think it does not worth it because there are two different paths only use two one time each